# Cannot figure out why PHP to C# .NET will not symmetrically encrypt/decrypt

Tags: c#, php, .net, encryption, cryptography

I've been working on this for a while and I don't know much about either PHP or C#.  We are building an application that is using AES 128 CBC mode encryption to store things in the database.  One part is PHP and JS, the other is C# .NET WPF.

The person who wrote the PHP used the Mcrypt library to crypt/decrypt.  I'm using the Chilkat library to encrypt/decrypt.  Chilkat had a default C# example that is supposed to mimic the PHP Mcrypt.

Currently I can symmetrically encrypt/decrypt things on .Net, and .Net can decrypt anything from PHP.  However the PHP side cannot decrypt anything that I encrypt to the database from the .Net side.

I've narrowed at least part of down to encoding issues, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  The decryption scheme on PHP side usually decrypts to ASCII, but for things that I send it decrypts to UTF-8.  I've tried to decrypt it then encode from UTF-8 to ASCII to no avail.

I'll show you the in/outputs and the functions. The IV is being set to 16 ASCII 0s to help my debugging along even though it shouldn't really matter.

input from .Net to mcrypt_encrypt func: string "1220"
output: 3tRIG7qUxUsU7WoXDybRRcdQRobOfeFGtQ438V7XRD8=
Parameter input into database = 'same as above'

input of PHP side decrypt func = 3tRIG7qUxUsU7WoXDybRRcdQRobOfeFGtQ438V7XRD8=  'same as above'

output of the mcrypt_decrypt function = ��J���{$�Z'?�u 'iconv says utf-8 encoding'

Ask for anything else and I'll get it if it would help.  I'm sure this is some stupid easy problem I can't see.

PHP side - if it matters the PHP charset is set to UTF-8

```
function encrypt($input)
{

    $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

/*No longer using random iv :(
    $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);*/

    //use 16 zeros 
    $this->iv = '0000000000000000';

    $encrypted = $this->iv .mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, KEY, $input, MODE, $this->iv);

    //Finally encode this as base 64, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);

    return $encrypted;
}



function decrypt($input)
{
    /*Get our message back!!!
    First decode the base 64 string. Note, de/encoding bas 64 != encryption*/
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($input);

    //Get the iv back out for decryption
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    //$iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);*/
    $iv_dec = '0000000000000000';

    //Now get the text of encrypted message (all but the iv in front)
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);        

    //Now decrypt the message
$plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, KEY, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

//Test
//test
    //$plaintext_dec = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $plaintext_dec); 
//echo mb_detect_encoding($plaintext_dec, "auto");
//echo $plaintext_dec;

    /*However, we might now have blank space @ end of output b/c
    remember we de/encrypt via block, so a 10 char long message
    could be padded to 16 char long with blank spaces. Get rid of those.*/
    $plaintext_dec = trim($plaintext_dec);

    //return so we can compare to, i.e., original input
return $plaintext_dec;
}
```

.NET C#

```
    public string mcrypt_encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(crypt.IV) + plainText;
        byte[] myText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

        //  Do 128-bit AES encryption:
        byte[] cipherText = crypt.EncryptBytes(myText);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }

    public string mcrypt_decrypt(string cipher_text)
    {

        byte[] cipher_dec = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher_text);

        byte[] plainBytes = crypt.DecryptBytes(cipher_dec);

        string decrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes);

        string plain_text = decrypted.Substring(16, decrypted.Length - 16);

        return plain_text.TrimEnd('\0');
    }
```

C# Chilkat init: 
         //  AES is also known as Rijndael.

```
          crypt.CryptAlgorithm = "aes";

        //  CipherMode may be "ecb" or "cbc"
        crypt.CipherMode = "cbc";

        //  KeyLength may be 128, 192, 256
        crypt.KeyLength = 128;

        //  Pad with NULL bytes (PHP pads with NULL bytes)
        crypt.PaddingScheme = 3;

        //  EncodingMode specifies the encoding of the output for
        //  encryption, and the input for decryption.
        //  It may be "hex", "url", "base64", or "quoted-printable".
        crypt.EncodingMode = "hex";

        //  The secret key must equal the size of the key.  For
        //  256-bit encryption, the binary secret key is 32 bytes.
        //  For 128-bit encryption, the binary secret key is 16 bytes.
        string keyAscii = @"&=*FS6wksG@Zs3qG";
        crypt.SecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyAscii);
        crypt.Charset = "ASCII";

        crypt.SetEncodedIV("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", "ascii");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variety of different problems here. The issue causing the problem you seeing in not being able to decrypt in PHP data that was encrypted in .NET is that in the PHP version you're performing a `substr` on the *ciphertext* prior to decryption. The comments in the code indicate that you're removing the IV, except that that seems to have only been relevant in a prior version of your code when you were (correctly) using a random IV each time - now you're just discarding the first 16 bytes of ciphertext which due to the mode of operation corrupts the subsequent data block.

The other problem (though masked by the fact that you're discarding the first 16 bytes of the plaintext data when decrypting in .NET) is that the IV you're using in .NET (16 bytes of `0x00`) is not the same as the IV you're using in PHP (16 '0' characters = 16 bytes of `0x30`).

I would suggest reverting to using a random IV for every encryption and prepending the IV to the ciphertext *after* encryption When decrypting, read the IV from the first bytes of the ciphertext then decrypt the remainder. This is much more secure than having a static IV, especially when the data being encrypted is likely to often be the same.

Comment: Yes.  This was it.  So I tried to convert the php to hex and output it, but I guess I performed it wrong since I thought it was all 0x00.  When I changed that and changed back to getting the substring it fixed everything.  Thank you so much I could not thnk straight about this haha.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like it's a simple character encoding issue. Your C# code is getting the ASCII representation of your string and encrypting that, but your PHP code is decrypting it and expecting it to be UTF-8.

Try swapping your `Encoding.ASCII` calls for `Encoding.UTF8` and make sure your `crypt.Charset` and `crypt.SetEncodedIV` are UTF8 as well

Comment: Nope.  1008.48 is the input and it comes out jarbled.  Like I said.  The output encoding of the PHP decrypt function is ASCII if it gets things that the PHP code put in itself.  If the C# code puts it in, then PHP decrypt function output is UTF-8.  I've tried just enccoding it to ASCII to no avail.  And I can decrypt everything PHP encrypts.